# What's the function of the symbol '&' after roscore?

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The statement 'roscore &' offten appears before 'rosparam set /use_sim_time true'.

What's the function of the symbol `&` after `roscore`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197750/what%27s-the-function-of-the-symbol-%27&%27-after-roscore?/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2014-11-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is more of a general Linux question, but from the manpage of `bash` (likely your shell):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.

In other words: adding the '&' allows you to continue to use the terminal, while `roscore` is running in the background. If you did not add the '&', `roscore` would start and all input (into the terminal window) would be directed to `roscore`. You'd need a second terminal to do your work in.

---

For reference: `man bash`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on 2014-11-19**:
Thank you so much.

How do I terminate the `roscore`?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-11-19**:
Just Ctrl+c

**Comment by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on 2014-11-19**:
I run other command after `roscore &`, and I find I can not use `Ctrl+C` to terminate it.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-11-19**:
you run it in the same terminal ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-19**:
Termination of background tasks can be tricky. You could use `pkill`: `pkill roscore`. Note that this will `kill` the first `roscore` process that it matches.

**Comment by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on 2014-11-19**:
Yes.  I run other command such as `ls` after `roscore &`, and the terminal can correctly display the files. However, I can not use `Ctrl+C` to terminate `roscore` after I run `ls`.

**Comment by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on 2014-11-19**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-11-19**:
You can use `fg` to bring running "jobs" to the "foreground". So if you type `jobs` you'll see a list of all running jobs. They'll all have a unique number like `[#]`. So if `roscore` was job 1, you could type `fg %1` and that would bring `roscore` to the foreground and Ctrl-C could kill it.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-11-19**:
Just typing `fg` brings the "last" job to the foreground (the one with the "+" next to it's number). You can use `bg` to set jobs to run in the background that are currently in the foreground. Read more here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/unix-background-job/

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-19**:
@jarvisschultz: excellent suggestion. Using `jobs` is indeed a good way to work with background tasks.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-19**:
You can also use the job ID with the `kill` command to terminate a job without bringing it to the foreground; for example `kill %1` will send a sigint (ctrl-c) to job #1.

**Comment by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on 2014-11-20**:
Thank you so much!